# How do i import a csv file with one column as timeformat hh:mm:ss and plot it in x axis with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is how my data from the csv file looks like.

```
Time stamp     kW
09:41:12   5.412224215
09:41:22   5.057871807
09:41:32   5.357250571
09:41:42   5.427124444
09:41:52   5.485060159
09:42:02   4.942689557
09:42:19   4.914225079
09:42:29   5.032617133
09:42:39   5.131685175
09:42:49   61.05746329
```

Im trying to import it and plot it the x_axis as hh:ss:ss.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
headers = ["Time stamp", "kW"]
dataset = pd.read_csv('Wash_Data1.csv',sep = ";",names = headers)
dataset.plot()
```

[X-axis doesnt display the x values. What i want is this format 09:42:49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EINQk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [28]: df = df.set_index(pd.to_timedelta(df['Time stamp']))

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
           Time stamp         kW
Time stamp
09:41:12     09:41:12   5.412224
09:41:22     09:41:22   5.057872
09:41:32     09:41:32   5.357251
09:41:42     09:41:42   5.427124
09:41:52     09:41:52   5.485060
09:42:02     09:42:02   4.942690
09:42:19     09:42:19   4.914225
09:42:29     09:42:29   5.032617
09:42:39     09:42:39   5.131685
09:42:49     09:42:49  61.057463

In [30]: ax = df[['kW']].plot()

In [33]: ax.set_xticklabels(df['Time stamp'])

In [34]: df.index.dtype
Out[34]: dtype('<m8[ns]')

In [35]: df.dtypes
Out[35]:
Time stamp     object
kW            float64
dtype: object
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is definitely too good for me to keep my silly one liner around :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, but it will work for the specified in the question timeseries, so please undelete it!

Comment: So will yours! And it does the same thing, only better. Trust me, I'd feel better with it gone.